# Change the date time format of an existing DateTime instance of Joda

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have two date fields. A user can choose a date from a jQuery date-time picker which is then converted into the UTC format (via a custom property editor of Spring) and populated into a Java bean upon the submission of the form.

These `DateTime` instances from the Java bean are retrieved by [`org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) via reflection like,

```
final Object object1 = PropertyUtils.getProperty(beanObject, firstDate);
final Object object2 = PropertyUtils.getProperty(beanObject, secondDate);
```

These objects are type-cast to `DateTime`.

```
if(object1!=null && object2!=null)
{
    final DateTime startDate=((DateTime)object1).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
    final DateTime endDate=((DateTime)object2).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));

    System.out.println("startDate = "+startDate+"\nendDate = "+endDate);
}
```

This produces the following output.

```
startDate = 2013-02-17T22:45:59.000+05:30
endDate = 2013-02-18T22:46:00.000+05:30
```

I need to conver these dates into this format - `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

The following approach which I have tried doesn't work.

```
DateTime newStartDate=new DateTime(startDate.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
DateTime newEndDate=new DateTime(startDate.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

System.out.println("newStartDate = "+newStartDate+"\nnewEndDate = "+newEndDate);
```

It gives the following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "17-Feb-2013
>   22:45:59" is malformed at "-Feb-2013 22:45:59"

So how to convert these dates into the required format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DateTime` doesn't have any format. It has a value, which is a number of milliseconds since 1st Jan. 1970, and a chronology. It's only when you transform a `DateTime` to a String that you need to choose a format. And you know how to do that already, since you're doing it in your question.

So what you're trying to do just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I didn't mention in my question though actually, I would like to compare two dates, if one is sooner, later or  equal to the other **ignoring the second** part from `DateTime` (i.e comparing them only with `HH:mm` and not with `HH:mm:ss`). Ignoring the time portion in its entirely is easy with Joda and can be done straight-away something like - `if(DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(startDate, endDate)==0){...}` (for equality). But I'm not sure how to ignore the specific portion in `DateTime` (`ss` in my case). Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: `DateTime dateTimeWithoutSeconds = originalDateTime.withMillis(0).withSecondOfMinute(0);` gets you anotherDateTime identical to the first one, but with the secodns and milliseconds set to 0. Do that with both instances, and compare the respective results. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html

Comment: `final DateTime startDate=((DateTime)object1).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata")).withMillis(0).withSecondOfMinute(0);` returns `startDate = 1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30`

Comment: Yes, so what? That's what you want. The date doesn't have seconds and milliseconds anymore. Now compare these two dates, to see which one is the greatest.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
        DateTime firstDate = formatter.parseDateTime("16-Feb-2012 12:03:45").withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillis(0);
        DateTime secondDate = formatter.parseDateTime("17-Feb-2013 12:03:45").withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillis(0);` then comparing them like `firstDate.isBefore(secondDate)`, `firstDate.isAfter(secondDate)` and `firstDate.equals(secondDate)` returns `false`, `false` and `true` respectively. Since it isn't the actual question, I will put it as a new one.

Comment: The code in the comment is quite illusive and is not readable. You may ignore it. Thank you very much.